# using facebook access token from different host?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

Let say I obtain a facebook page access token from one machine and another machine have it.

Is it allowed if both machines use that access token simultaneously, at the same time, to call facebook API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use the same token on different machines.